# Delete with modal in data ajax laravel 10

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

After the first click to retrieve data('product-id') from delete-btn, I can obtain $product->id and successful deleted.

Next i click to delete another product. It failed and i think it didnt retrieve data('product-id') from delete-btn. Anyone know where is my issue

this is my js code

```
$(function () {
    $("#delete-btn").click(function () {
        var productId = $(this).data('product-id');
        $('#deleteModal').data('product-id', productId);
    });

    $('#deleteModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).removeData('product-id');
        $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
    });

    $("#deleteModal .delete-btn-modal").click(function () {
        var productId = $('#deleteModal').data('product-id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/products/' + productId,
            type: 'DELETE',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.message);

                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: 'Success!',
                    text: data.message,
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        $('.table').load(location.href + ' .table')
                    }
                });
            },
    

        $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

My button on index

```
 <button id="delete-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-btn inline-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" data-product-id="{{ $product->id }}">
       Delete
</button>
```

My modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you want to delete?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-btn-modal" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `and i think it didnt retrieve data` You have to debug this. It is big part in your issue. You should tell us what is in `request()->all()` array at controller's method.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function DeleteData(e){
  var productId = $(e).data('product-id');
  console.log(productId);
}
```

```html
<button class="delete-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-btn inline-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" onClick="DeleteData(this)" data-product-id="{{ $product->id }}">
           Delete
</button>
```

**button has different id for every product. You should use onclick method to call function in jquery.**
**Try this code i hope this code work for you**

Answer (score 0):

You button has same `id` for every product. You should use class instead

```
<button class="delete-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-btn inline-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" data-product-id="{{ $product->id }}">
  Delete
</button>
```

Comment: I tried and still have same issue